# How to know whether pro*c is installed on my system?

Tags: oracle, centos

How to know if proc (pre-compiler) is installed on my system?

[image]

I went into different folders to check if a file named proc is present, I got this (if it is of any help):
[image]

[image]

Comment: Pro*C is a tool outside the database, so it won't appear in `v$version`. That link is looking for an Oracle 12c Instant Client installation, which either doesn't exist at all, or didn't include the precompilers package. Your SQL\*Plus seems to be version 11.2 XE. From the command line, does `$ORACLE_HOME/proc` exist? What do you get if you just run `proc`, the same way you run `sqlplus`?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have searched both of them but it didn't work. I have attached another screenshot of what I have done. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, I meant `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/proc`, but [Pro\*C is not included with XE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC116). If you stick to XE you can get Pro\*C as part of [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html). That broken link suggests you used to have it; maybe you just moved the directory it was in?

Comment: (Also, please don't post images when you could just copy and paste the text - much easier to read, is searchable, and images are blocked for some people)